# Same space between bootstrap grid column

Tags: bootstrap-4

```html
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input type="text" name="languageSearch" id="languageSearch" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" value="" style="background-color: #ffff;" placeholder="Search Language" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search" class="btn-md btn-primary form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static" type="button">Create New Language</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Please, refer the image. Here i want to get same space between all 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding classes `d-flex justify-content-center` to **col-sm-2** . That will align the Search button in center of the column so that there will be some space between all cols.

Comment: Thank You @justCurious. It worked. Can you give me an idea how to get "Create New Language" button to align left so, the space between "Search" & "Create New Language" button will have the same space as like textbox & search button.

Comment: First of all Im happy that it worked. And now what you have to do is upvote the answer buddy or you can even close it by clicking on that check button along my answer.

Comment: And there are simple bootstrap classes for vertical and horizontal alignment of an element. Kindly study them first. You can provide justify-content-start now to the col-sm-4 to align the elemnt at the start of div.

Comment: Thank You @JustCurious. I'll see the bs classes, and I voted your answer. Thank You.